# What is the “free symmetric monoidal category” 2-monad?

Tags: ct.category-theory, quantum-mechanics, monads

I have come across an n-category cafe post where someone describes a monad that generates symmetric monoidal categories.  Can someone give details, like what is the base category, what exactly is the endofunctor and natural isomorphisms for “free symmetric monoidal category” 2-monad?  Could this generate the category of finite dimensional hilbert spaces and unitary maps?

I have been reading [this post](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/07/morton_and_vicary_on_the_categ.html) by Jeffery Morton.  He describes the following  “free symmetric monoidal category” 2-monad:

> The bosonic Fock space is then ⊕nC⊗sn, the direct sum of all symmetric
>   tensor products of some number of copies of this space. One way to say
>   this is that the symmetric tensor product of a space V with itself is
>   the equalizer of two maps V⊗V→V⊗V, namely the identity and the swap
>   map. Likewise, V⊗sn is the equalizer of all the permutation
>   automorphisms that appear because V⊗n is automatically a
>   representation of Sn. So the symmetric product is the trivial
>   representation.
>
> Since C⊗sn≅C, this is just a sum of a bunch of 1-dimensional spaces,
>   each of which describes an n-particle system, which again has only one
>   state. The only thing to say about this state is that it has n
>   particles in it. Jamie’s original paper explains this by means of a
>   monad on Hilb, which is essentially the “free commutative monoid”
>   monad: the Fock space is the free commutative monoid on C. This fact
>   gives a bunch of special maps, including a bialgebra structure on the
>   Fock space, and the raising and lowering operators can be constructed
>   out of this. The commutation relations are a consequence of that.
>
> Now, groupoidifying this is a categorification, so this description
>   has to be weakened. To start with, we take a groupoid describing a
>   system with only one configuration (the “it’s there” state for our
>   particle). This will be the trivial groupoid 1, with one object and
>   only the identity morphism. Then we want to take the “groupoidified
>   Fock space”.
>
> ***> Since groupoids live in a 2-category, the equivalent of the “free
>   commutative monoid” monad turns out to be a bit weaker, namely the
>   “free symmetric monoidal category” 2-monad***. We get a “direct sum”
>   (i.e. in Span(Gpd), the disjoint union) of a bunch of objects which
>   show up as certain 2-limits. In particular, we freely generate a bunch
>   of objects like (⊗...⊗), and we must get not EQUATIONS, but
>   ISOMORPHISMS corresponding to all the switch maps. This is essentially
>   where the groupoid of finite sets and bijections come from: think of
>    as the groupoid which contains exactly the 1-element set - the free
>   symmetric monoidal category this generates is the groupoid which
>   contains all finite sets and their bijections.

Comment: Have you looked at gs-monoidal categories? This may be close to what you want, or not: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0f1f/352eb2a614e0f77958292ab59ec50a2ee6c7.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a 2-monad $P$ on $\mathrm{Cat}$ whose strict algebras are symmetric strict monoidal categories, and whose pseudo-algebras are "unbiased" symmetric monoidal categories.  On objects, $PA$ is the category whose objects are finite lists of objects of $A$, and in which a morphism $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\to (b_1,\dots,b_m)$ consists of a bijection $\sigma : \{1,\dots,n\} \to \{1,\dots,m\}$ (so that in particular $n=m$) and morphisms $f_i : a_i \to b_{\sigma i}$ in $A$.  The unit $A \to P A$ sends $a$ to the 1-element list $(a)$, and the multiplication $P P A \to P A$ removes parentheses.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: it looks very interesting. It makes a monoidal category out of any category. Are the functions $f_i$ free to be any morphisms mappingI$a_i$ to $b_{\sigma_i}$?The bijections $\sigma$, are they like connecting the input wires to a box in a string diagram to the output wires? What is their purpose?

Comment: Yes, the $f_i$ are any morphisms in $A$ from $a_i$ to $b_{\sigma i}$.  The bijections can indeed be thought of as connecting input to output wires; without them, the monoidal structure would not be symmetric.  For instance, the twist $(a) \otimes (b) = (a,b) \cong (b,a) = (b) \otimes (a)$ has $\sigma$ the transposition bijection with $f_1 = \mathrm{id}_{a}$ and $f_2 = \mathrm{id}_{b}$.